# error in the following code

Tags: java, exception

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.println("Enter the String:");
String str = br.readLine();//error: must be caught or declared
String reverseStr="";
for(int i=str.length()-1;i>=0;--i) 
    reverseStr += str.charAt(i);

    System.out.println(reverseStr);
```

Should i include try catch block?

Comment: could you copy/ past the error message ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`readLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) method can throw a checked exception (an `IOException` to be precise); you have to catch it or declare it in your prototype.

---

**Resources :**

- [oracle.com - Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch/throw exception.

read line can throw IOException - If an I/O error occurs

So it must be taken care of

- [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, or throw the exception out of your containing method.